# Basic dynamic 3D collision in LWJGL

Tags: java, collision, lwjgl

sorry about my last question it was a bit all over the place.

I have hit a huge road block with a game I am coding for a friend and i need to learn dynamic collision. A tutorial would be great, a very basic one and i have already seen the NeHe collision detection tutorial and did not seem to pull much from it.

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a invisible 3d box surrounding your entities and check when two or more of said boxes have intersecting xyz coordinates. I can't supply you with code, but I know it works. You would have to figure out the coding for yourself